# Partial Correlation VS. Correlation Threshold in brain network graph

Tags: correlation, references, partial-correlation

Partial correlation (or inverse of covariance matrix) and correlation threshold are two common methods to construct the brain network in fMRI data.

Theoretically, partial correlation should perform better since it has good explanations about conditional independence as Markov random field.

But I cannot find any papers to prove this, partial correlation outperforms correlation threshold method practically, nor prove it by myself.

Could you give me any ideas? or any papers comparing these two methods?